# Getting SerializableException while saving data into isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, jsonserializer

I am working on windows phone 8 app. In which I need to call an api to get some response, that I am serializing and saving into local settings
    While saving these data I am getting an exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException'.

```
My Code is,

    string someData = responseDataDict["SomeData"].ToString();
    if someData != null) 
    {
       Dictionary<string, Object> someDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(someData);
       Datastore.SaveData = stringDict; 
    }

    public static Datastore
    {
       get
       {
          if (localSettings.Contains("SaveData"))
          {
             return (Dictionary<string, Object>)localSettings["SaveData];
             else
             return null;
          }
      }
      set
      {
          localSettings["SaveData"] = value; 
          localSettings.Save();
      }
 }
```

}

The response from api is,

```
"MESSAGE": "Some Message",
"UI_MESSAGE": {
    "LEFT": "OK",
    "RIGHT": "CANCEL",        
 }
```

I think the problem is in "UI_MESSAGE",

The Exception is,

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' with data contract name 'ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringJTokeneJCYCtcq:http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Please help me to resolve this issue, Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the Exception Message?

Comment: Hi  Florian, Thanks for your response,  I have edited the post, please check

Answer (score 0):

You can't (easily) serialize the data because the serializer doesn't know how to serialize `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` types.

We could try to figure out **how** to get the serializer working with this type, which may or may not take lots of time, or we could stop and think for a bit...

You grab the response data in the line

`string someData = responseDataDict["SomeData"].ToString();`

What is `someData`?  It's

```
{
"MESSAGE": "Some Message",
"UI_MESSAGE": {
    "LEFT": "OK",
    "RIGHT": "CANCEL",        
}
```

That's a json string.  A serialized javascript object.  *It's already bloody serialized.*

**Save that** in `localSettings`.

Comment: Thanks Will, I will directly save the json string into storage.